# Should I downvote a question because I think it is beckoning trouble?

Tags: support

**Question 1:** On Superuser, [someone had asked how to disable his/her page file](https://superuser.com/q/1175774/477799) in order to free more disk space! Naturally, I (and any technically aware person) know that this is very unwise. A computer without page file will not operate properly.

Should I downvote the question because I think the action is unwise?

**Question 2:** Someone has written an accurate answer for this question. Should I downvote the answer? (Of course, I didn't. I just edited it and wrote that the author of the answer assumes the OP knows the repercussions of his/her actions. And then upvoted it because it was accurate.)

Comment: I am removing the part about a specific individual. Your question should be neutral not calling out specific individuals.

Comment: @DavidPostill There is a difference between a "neutral" and a "neutralized" question.

Comment: Whatever. I stand by my comment and edit.

Comment: @FleetCommand I took a look at every one of your reputation changes, that took place over a year and half, and only one was because of my vote.  I accept your apology.

Comment: @FleetCommand if you believe I have unjustly voted one of your answers down then I apologize.

Comment: @Ramhound Of course you didn't find it in my rep log. I deleted the answers. (And the first time I did, it earned me a Peer Pressure achievement!) That said, my message doesn't have the word "unjustly". It was a statement of the fact: You downvoted. Should I too? Somehow, however, you think that I must think that just because you downvote a lot, you must be a bad person. Well, I don't think so. Life is not a fight and we are not here to hate each other. At least, I don't hate you. Do you hate me?

Comment: @FleetCommand, asking about an unwise action isn't one of the things downvotes are intended for.  If a Google search would show dozens of explanations on the first page that you would have to be nuts to do it, a downvote for lack of research might be warranted.  The question is clear, so that probably wouldn't be a downvote reason.  The last downvote reason is whether the question is useful.  Consider that a question about a stupid, dangerous practice could be useful to other novices, especially if it attracts a good answer.  It might be a candidate for an upvote.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's what I call an answer. Come on, now; post it as a reply instead of a comment and I'll give you the tick mark.

Comment: @FleetCommand You are clearly upset about the votes you received, and while I question the reason you think all of those votes were me, I still apologize.  If your going to say I do something, and the say something about being neutralized, then you can't say your feelings are not hurt

Comment: @Ramhound Again, that's far less often the case than you are probably imagining. The downvote itself: I have no way of knowing it was you. Your first comment: I have always thought it deserves a response. What happens next: One time you responded by recanting your comment and the vote count went up. Happy ending. In one other time, you said I am having a cow. Yes. I got upset. In our latest interaction, your comment was unfair, but since the OP gave me an upvote, I can't complain. I got +8 rep total.

Comment: I grew up watching `The Simpsons`, "don't have a cow man" or "you are having a cow" is simply a pop culture reference for me.  Similar to how I have said in the past, "don't make a mountain out of a molehill", which is a variant of the old idiom.  In other words a single vote means almost nothing with regards to the big picture, unless multiple votes follow, but that single vote also should be taken as a small hint that there might be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking about an unwise action isn't one of the things downvotes are intended for. If a Google search would show dozens of explanations on the first page that you would have to be nuts to do it, a downvote for lack of research might be warranted.

The question is clear, so that probably wouldn't be a downvote reason.

The last downvote reason is whether the question is useful. Consider that a question about a stupid, dangerous practice could be useful to other novices, especially if it attracts a good answer. It might be a candidate for an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Well, "OP has no idea what he's doing" isn't really something that I've seen in any guidelines.

I'd consider a few things.

Is this a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? OP is clearly trying to solve an underlying 'issue' based on misconceptions. The comments help us work out what's the real issue.

Since there's *misconceptions*, how best do we deal with that? A simple downvote dosen't really do much in the greater scheme of things in educating the user.

Unrelatedly *has the user done any research?*  If he clearly hasn't, downvoting is fine.

Sometimes, we also need to ask ourselves *are we missing something*? Here I don't quite see it but its worth considering.

So in this case, downvoting is optional, but not quite as helpful as one would like. The *right* thing depends on the question and situation.

Answers, well, you'd need to decide on the usefulness for yourself. I do personally prefer not to downvote good faith, on topic answers.

Comment: First, it is not an XY problem; it is an extension of the famous "what if I press this button?" case, i.e. the OP doesn't have problem, but the thrill of doing this certain thing has taken him. Second, forget the great scheme of things; a downvote has no value whatsoever. It is never helpful. It is a mean thing that we do to each other and I want to learn the rules of it.

Comment: Downvotes arn't mean. Downvotes are the clean me scratched in the dusty car of a question. Personally most questions I find bad enough to downvote, I find bad enough to closevote or at least comment so op learns. If I get one, the kindest thing one can do is comment and let me know why so I can do better.

Comment: That's a nice theory. Too bad it isn't the case. See this, for an example: http://superuser.com/q/1176075/477799